# How to change only one byte at address with gdb

Tags: gdb

I'd like to be able to change only one byte at a certain address with gdb.
The set * command always changes 4 counting from an address and if you don't provide all four it fills the rest with zeroes (or ffs depending on the signedness).

The syntax I'm using is `set * {address}=0x{bytes}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

treat address as pointer to `char` type

```
(gdb) set {char}address = 0x{bytes}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. But the cast is to a char, not a char * or am I missing something? I had tried casting to char * which resulted in 8 bytes being overwritten with my byte and trailing zeroes (the idea being you're placing a pointer at the address so it should be 8 bytes long).

Comment: You're right, I didn't make it clear.